# Локальный чат, вопросы

Tags: c#, чат

Хочу сделать локальный чат, работающий через один маршрутизатор (раздача с телефона, не обязательно с интернетом, модем и т.п.). Однако не знаю с чего начать, не хватает знаний.
Поделитесь, пожалуйста, своими знаниями. Какие подводные камни ждут, что предстоит учесть и т.п.

Comment: Пробовали просто Jabber поставить?

Comment: Мне нужно написать чат, на основе блокчейна, поэтому спрашиваю.

Comment: Начать лучше с изучения литературы, особенно если у вас есть понимание, что не хватает знаний. Видите ли, stackoverflow для конкретных вопросов, ваш слишком широкий. Также хорошо дробить задачу на подзадачи, "есть слона по кусочкам": напишите сначала "просто чат" (вы уже на этой фазе можете пропасть на пару месяцев), потом думайте в каком месте применить блокчейн и зачем.

Answer (score 1):

Локальный чат это одно из элементарного. Гайдов по этому поводу огромное количество.

Для начала советую обратить внимание на [Client/Server Chat](https://metanit.com/sharp/net/4.4.php)

Это консольный чат в котором есть все что может потребоваться для реализации полноценного чата

Так же довольно интересная [статья](https://shwanoff.ru/blockchain/amp/) именно про создание блокчейн хранилища на языке c#

Comment: `Мне нужно написать чат, на основе блокчейна`

Comment: Начните с чего-то более простого. Изучите для начала как работают сети и как происходит обмен между узлами сети, изучите разницу UDP и TCP , потом окунитесь в азы блокчейна и тд. тп. 

Сомневаюсь что вам кто-то предоставит готовый проект. Если уж не осилите то есть фриланс)

Comment: вопрос не мой, я просто процитировал автора вопроса. Я сделал это, так как ваш ответ не отвечает на поставленный вопрос.

Comment: @tym32167, Ну лично я понял что автор спрашивает о всех аспектах создания локального чата и с чем он может столкнуться при его создании. Я предоставил ссылку с гайдом от которого можно оттолкнуться.

Comment: мне не непонятно, как можно написать чат на основе блокчейна отталкиваясь от простых примеров клиент-серверных чатов? Опишите подробней вашу мысль. С моей точки зрения, между клиент-серверным чатом и чатом на основе блокчейна общее только одно слово в названии и больше ничего.

Comment: обмен данными по сети у них общий. Каким образом вы собираетесь писать что либо связанное с обменом данных в сети без самых элементарных знаний?

Comment: ну это то же самое, что сказать, что надо кодить для того, чтобы что то написать. Давайте посоветуем автору курсы по c# отдельным ответом? Ответы же для того, чтобы отвечать на вопрос, я вам и пишу, что ваш ответ - не отвечает на вопрос. Он в общем полезный, знать про сокеты это хорошо, я не спорю, просто он не отвечает на то, что спросил автор.